# How to get rid of 'System.Configutation.dll' error - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, linker-errors

I get this error using `ad-hoc` build or any other, except for Debug. `System` refered to the dll. The error could be a result of System.Data and using SqlCommand and SqlClient. I use the Mono 1.0 dlls and have installed `System.Data.Common` and the latest version of `SqlClient` via `Nuget`. But how to avoid that error? Is there an alternate sql package?

If I use All instead of `None` at `link` a `System.Configuration.ConfigurationException` error appears.